# Borrar informacion especifica dentro de un .txt creado

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un programa en python que al abrirse necesita poder ver la informacion guardada en el archivo .txt y tambien poder borrar ciertas lineas. Logre que lo guarde y lo muestre en pantalla, pero no se como borrarlo. Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Edita la pregunta, coloca lo que has realizado, incluyendo lo que has investigado y lo que has intentado. Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.